# Is there a way to unban an user from a fb-comment embedded in a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

One of our moderator have banned an user in moderator view from a fb comment embed using a tag like the one below.

```
<div id="comments" class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.dhnet.be/s/art/5429063b357030e61042ebda" data-width="620" data-numposts="10" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

It's been now  4 days that I'm trying to find a way to unban that user without any luck. Does anybody know how to do that ?

Thanks in advance,

Lint

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/#faqmoderate

Comment: I don't see anywhere any mention about un-banning someone.